# How to create ios 14 widgets in Flutter app?

Tags: swift, flutter, widget, ios14

i have created an app with flutter  for ios and now i have to create widgets which must be customizable in app. I cant find a solution on how to make the connection between ios widgetskit and flutter app which takes data from api. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: I have not tried this tutorial, but seems there are solutions out there => [Develop an iOS 14 Widget in Flutter with SwiftUI](https://itnext.io/develop-an-ios-14-widget-in-flutter-with-swiftui-e98eaff2c606)